# Socket connection refused after first message

Tags: python, matlab, sockets

I communicate Python with Matlab via sockets. However, even before going there, I want to test sockets with [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat). So I establish server using `nc -lkp 25771`, and make Python client to send a message to this server:

```
import socket
host = 'localhost'
port = 25771
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))
s.send('Hello there')
s.close()
```

After running `python client.py` server prints out 'Hello there'; however, after I try to run client script one more time it raises exception.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "client.py", line 13, in 
>       s.connect((host,port))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
>       return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
>   socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Why the same command raises the error second time? What changes after my first command?

Comment: Are you sure you passed `-k` option to the `nc` command?

Comment: Does the problem appear even if you wait few seconds between calls?

Comment: I use k option. However, now it's clear why there is a connection error. Once I ran my script and close connection, it shuts nc server down. The question now is how to make nc to listen to second client after the first is done?

Answer (score 0):

You are using traditional version of netcat (netcat-traditional) which doesn't support -k option. you can confirm checking the man page of your netcat by typing man nc in your terminal .

Install the netcat-openbsd version using the command 
sudo apt-get install netcat-openbsd

now switch to netcat-openbsd version using the command

sudo update-alternatives --config nc 
and choose the netcat-openbsd .

now you can use nc -lk 25771 .
this listens on port 25771 for multiple connections .

you can also use the commands discussed here 
[Netcat: using nc -l port_number instead of nc -l -p port_number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318780/netcat-using-nc-l-port-number-instead-of-nc-l-p-port-number)